# loop through an array and choose specific to setstate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

New react developer here, here i have two API's, first one gives an object :

```
{ id: "98s7faf", isAdmin: true, name: "james"}
```

second one gives an array of objects :

```
[
  { billingName: "trump", driverName: "james" },
  { billingName: "putin", driverName: "alex" },
  { billingName: "kalle", driverName: "james" },
  { billingName: "sussu", driverName: "trump" },
  { billingName: "vladimir", driverName: "james" },
]
```

my question is, when user goes to the page, the page should automatically check both API'S, from first api `name` and from second api `driverName`, and if those two have same value then take that specific object from an array and pass it to these:

```
setOrders(res);
setRenderedData(res);
```

so at the moment there are three objects (those which have value of `james`) inside an array which matches `name` from first api, so it should pass those, and the rest which have different value it should not let them pass. here is my code, what have i done wrong ? instead of `some(({ driverName })` i need some kind of filter ?

```js
 useEffect(() => {
  api.userApi.apiUserGet().then((res1?: User ) => {
  return api.caApi.apiCaGet(request).then((res?: CaDto[]) 
  => {
    if (res.some(({ driverName }) => driverName === res1?.name)) {
      setOrders(res);
      setRenderedData(res);
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
});
}, [api.caApi, api.userApi]);
```

Comment: What isn't working? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: it is important that 'name: "james"' and 'driverName: "james"' both have exactly same value to be accepted at the moment both are 'james' so it is accepted, but if one is something else then it should not pass 'res' to useState ' setOrders(res);
      setRenderedData(res);'

Comment: so only accept 'res' to be passed to those two useStates IF 'name' and 'driverName' values matches

Comment: If you only want values where `driverName === 'james'`, could you not filter the list by name and check if it's empty? If not empty, call `setState` with the filtered result?

Comment: it doesnt matter if its 'james', my point is that 'driverName' and 'name' values should match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to filter your response to extract the right objects given your condition.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  api.userApi.apiUserGet().then((res1?: User ) => {
  return api.caApi.apiCaGet(request).then((res?: CaDto[]) 
  => {
    const filteredData = res?.filter(({ driverName }) => driverName === res1?.name);
    if(filteredData?.length) {
      setOrders(filteredData);
      setRenderedData(filteredData);
      console.log(filteredData);
    }
  });
});
}, [api.caApi, api.userApi]);
```

**note:** having 2 states that holds the same values (orders, renderedData) is not a good practice, you might consider to refactor your logic.

Comment: Cannot find name 'filteredData'.ts(2304)

Comment: i need to push it and check it takes time

Comment: it is not working, 'driverName: "Testikuljettaja"' and 'name: "james"', so here is two different value, but it still let it pass

Comment: now it should be working, you can check it.

Comment: did you change something ?

Comment: Yes, setState values I was passing res instead of filteredData